# Is this the correct time complexity of my algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity

I have an algorithm broken down into the pseudish code below. But the gist of it is, we go through every person in a list, we then ask them to talk to all of their friends. Every time we choose a person to eval in the list, it costs $log N$ time. Every time that person talks to a friend it costs $log N$. What is the time complexity? Is my answer right?

My answer: $O(N \cdot log(E \cdot log(N)))$

```
List[People] // N

forall People in List:  //O(Log N) to get a person in list
   forall friends of Person:    // Person has a set of Friends E that is [0, N) 
       Person.talkToFriend(friend)  //Costs O[LogN] to talk to a friend
```

Answer (score 1):

For each of the n people in the list you do $|E|\cdot log(n)$ plus the time of getting it from the list, which is $log(n)$. So the time you start with is complexity: $O(n(log(n)+(log(n)|\cdot|E|)))=O(n\cdot|E|\cdot log(n))$

Assuming E could be as big as n, you could simply say the time complexity is $O(log(n)\cdot n^2)$.